# XCode: CoreData.Framework strange behavior with id

Tags: xcode, cocoa, frameworks

I have found a strange lines like:

`id *_optimizationHints;` `<- in NSManagedObjectModel.h`

`id* _cd_snapshots;` `<- in NSManagedObject.h`

`id** _kvcPropertyAccessors;` `<- in NSEntityDescription`

`id* _debuggingRecords;` `<- in NSManagedObjectContext.h`
`id *_cachedObsInfoByEntity;` `<- in NSManagedObjectContext.h`

When i try to compile a project with **ARC** option, i see error like this: *Pointer to non-const type 'id' with no explicit ownership*

What's wrong? As i read from similar questions, i need to replace `id *` -> `id`

But this is Main CoreDate.Framework!

I can't understand this.

Can anybody explain this 'joke'?

Answer (score 4):

I encounter similar issue this morning. Seems the problem is due to the Core Data has been built in somehow. When we import the CD framework, I have to go to Building Phases to add dependency framework instead of drag and drop directly from Finder. Hopefully this is helpful

Comment: not bad, i solved this problem too, but what is it? really strange 'joke' for developers?

Comment: Same here. Instead of going to the target settings and adding CoreData.framework to the linked frameworks, I thought I had taken a shortcut by dragging & dropping from a second project. It appears that for whatever reason this does not work: I got the same 'pointer to non const' compile error. I fixed this by removing the drag&dropped version, and removing and re-adding the framework dependency the regular way. Don't know why this is any different, but it is. Thanks for this info!

Answer (score 4):

I have run into the same problem today, while converting an existing project that I want to split into a static library and a public code part. I followed the instructions here: https://github.com/jverkoey/iOS-Framework

It is true that I added the CoreData.framework by dragging and dropping from my earlier project. However I deleted it and re-added it like you pointed out (mulitple times) but I still get the same errors that you reported.

EDIT: This was my problem:
I deleted the frameworks and readded them from inside Xcode. My problem was that there actually was a "CoreData" subdirectory inside my project directory that wasn't deleted.

Solution:
After deleting it in Finder, and re-adding it to the "Link Binary with Libraries" the problems went away